# What shapes are the explosion hitboxes in Tears of the Kingdom?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

When you create an explosion in *The Legend of Zelda: Tears of the Kingdom*, it appears as a big cloud of smoke and fire. However, it seems unlikely that the explosion hitbox has that exact shape. I know that the zonai device time bombs explode into perfect spheres, but the other types seem… less precise. I would like to know the shapes of the explosions created by the following items:

- Bomb barrels
- Bomb flowers
- Time bombs (the ones that aren't zonai devices)

Comment: What makes you think they are not all spherical ?

Comment: @Z1proW Maybe they are. However, when a bomb flower explodes, the resulting cloud of smoke and fire is *not* a sphere.

Comment: @User23415: Given that you are referring to explosion "hitboxes", it seems you are aware that a hitbox is usually different from the visuals of an object (hence why it is a different concept). In light of that, your comment reply doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although in the animation the cloud is not spherical, the hitbox of every type of bomb is perfectly spherical, and it hits entities slightly before than the animation does, like with *Remote Bombs* in Breath of the Wild (that’s the reason windbombs work).